# Linux: using csv as source for token replacement of config files

Tags: linux, csv, configuration-files

In .net we have a very easy token replacement stategy, to configure web.configs for multiple environments.

The developer creates a tag [%TokenName%] and then fills out a matching column name in a CSV file. We then run ConfigGen.exe and it does the search/replace for us.

I'm curious if anyone follows this type of procedure in Linux java builds, and if so, how?

Overview:
1. the first column of CSV is the environment name
2. for each column in the CSV the program searches the config file for matching tokens [%ColumnName%]
3. If the ColumnName is found, the value from the CSV is replaced into the file
4. This process is repeated for each row, as each row identifies a different environment name

Thanks.